# Unable to launch RIDE.py after python updated to 2.7.15 version

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

In my machine python 2.7.15 is auto updated from 2.7.14. When to try to launch Ride.py it throws an error wxPython not found. You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 or 3.0.2 or newer with Unicode support to run RIDE. wxPython can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/

Although is wxpython 2.8.12.1 installed its doesn't recognize it. can anyone help out how can I over come this issue. I have Ride 2.0a1. should I downgrade ride or how can I fix this issue.

Comment: Please show the output of python (to be sure it is 32bit or 64bit). You did not mention what operative system is. (RIDE Version 2.0a1 is not from the official project. Where did you get it from?)

Comment: window 10 64 bit
But i have installed 32 bit Python version and wxpython 2.8.12.1
It from Robotframework-ride installed using pip command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a fresh reinstall:

1. uninstall wxpython
2. uninstall robotframework-ride
3. install wxPython 2.8.12.1 unicode 32bit for python2.7
   Package is https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe/download
4. install robotframework-ride version 1.5.2.1

   **pip install robotframework-ride**
5. install Pygments

   **pip install Pygments**

Comment: I have done above process but still daily morning when i launch my machine python is auto updated to 2.7.15. 
In command prompt it shows 2.7.15 where as in control panel its still 2.7.14 
I don't understand the logic behind this 
because of this update wxpython is not recognized to launch ride
can we uninstall ride alone and reinstall any other version if so could you help me out with the steps

Comment: Please always use the command window to debug this problem. You probably have more than on Python installed. Show us the output of: `python -i` and then `import wx` followed by `quit()`

Comment: Try the Slack conversation system, you get access at http://robotframework.org/#support . Then you can ask for help at #ride channel.